# using XPath in PHP always gives empty array

Tags: php, xml, magento, xpath

I am trying to call an XPath on a SimpleXMLElement, but I always get empty array.
This is the XML:

```
<Produkt>
    .....
    <Darstellung>
        <Info Art="Kurztext" Wert="some info!"/>
        <Info ... />

    </Darstellung>
</Produkt>
```

I tried this:

```
$shortDescription = $Produkt->xpath('//Darstellung/Info[@Art="Kurztext"]/@Wert');
$configurableProduct['short_description'] = (string)$shortDescription[0];
```

And this:

```
$configurableProduct['short_description'] = $Produkt->xpath('//Darstellung/Info[@Art="Kurztext"]/@Wert');
```

And also without `//` in the beginning of the XPath expression or with `/*`. But when I dump, I see that the array returned from the `xpath()` function is always empty.

The problem is not in unregistered namespace, because the XML file is not using namespaces. I am kinda out of ideas already... (tried some more things in the syntax, but don't remember them already).

P.S. Yes, I am sure `$Produkt` is a SimpleXMLElement object and I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
$xmlStr = '<Produkt>
    <Darstellung>
        <Info Art="Kurztext" Wert="some info!"/>
        <Info />

    </Darstellung>
</Produkt>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
$ret = $xml->xpath('//Darstellung/Info[@Art="Kurztext"]/@Wert');
var_dump((string)$ret[0]);
```

returns

```
string(10) "some info!"
```

Yes, $ret[0] is XMLObject, so you should cast it to string.

Comment: That does not help me. I load the XML from a file, not from a string. And my problem is not in failing to return the values correctly. It is in not having values to return at all.

Comment: @Syspect: creating from string or from file is not relevant. The code Alex offered is working, see: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QgR8tq. Post your relevant code, please.

Comment: @michi - I tried with another path as well (accessing other nodes for information) and it didn't work again. Then I tried both this one and the new one, through creating from string (instead of from file) and it worked! So the problem must be in SimpleXMLElement that I am working on, I guess (since this object contains the XML code that I am trying to get the information from). Any suggestions ?

Comment: @michi - now I tried having the full XML content from the file, loaded from a string (like the example Alexandr gave) and it works even with really short XPath expressions (although the info I am looking for is in a deep hierarchy). Then I tried loading the XML from a file and directly applying the `xpath()` function to the SimpleXMLElement object, but it doesn't work (I did that, because the object I was using initially was going through a lot of stuff in the system and it was tidious to track it whether everything is fine). 
So, in conclusion, from string - it works, from file - not!

Comment: @Syspect Do you get the same behavior with a very basic XML like `<root><test>Test</test></root>` from file? If you edit your question and post your code, we all can help you track the error.

Comment: @michi - thanks for the help, but I solved it. I just decided to test a very simple XML file, adding one by one the main elements of my original file until the moment when the code breaks - and I found the problem - namespaces! Although it looked like this is not the problem... :D